# Video frame for video file in a Rich Text field

Tags: craft-features

I am adding a video in a Rich Text field through file button in toolbar. I want to play these video in iframe. How can I do this..?

Or is there anyother option or plugin by which I can upload video which and add in richtext filed anywhere I want and show this in iframe on frontend.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to upload and host the video on your site's server, then I would create a field with an Asset field type and restrict the type to Video. Without further details, it's hard to understand why you'd want to handle it within a Rich Text field.

Since you're hosting the video, you don't need an iframe. Just use the HTML5 `<video>` tag...

```
{% for video in entry.FIELDNAME %}
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
<source src="{{ video.getUrl }}" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Your servers will be handling the bandwidth for video delivery though; which is why most people post to YouTube or Vimeo and use the iframe to pass it through. To do that, you'd use the include that Brad mentioned.

Comment: I have text content above the video and below the video so i think if i can handle this with the Rich Text so need to create an extra field for video asset.

Answer (score 0):

In your Rich Text field settings, if you select the "Standard" Redactor config that ships with a fresh Craft install (maps to the `.json` files in `craft/config/redactor`), it has the "Video" plugin selected by default.

[image]

That will add a Video button to your Rich Text field toolbar.

[image]

Clicking it will let you embed iframe code that you can output on the front-end of your site.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but i know about that. This video button help me to add video through embed code but I want to **upload** my video in my sites same as we upload images in our site.

Comment: Sorry... missed the upload part of the question.